# Does the c call sync do the same as the command sync?

Tags: c, linux, synchronization

Does the c call "sync" do the same as the linux command "sync"?
And if not how does they diff?

The C/C++ code is running on a Linux based system.

/Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `sync(8)` man page:

> The sync program does nothing but exercise the sync(2) system call.